# find the signed minimum value in a three dimensional matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, minimum

I have a 3D matrix d and I want to find the signed minimum value along the third dimension. Currently, I use following code

```
tmp = abs(d);
[row, col]=ndgrid(1:size(d,1),1:size(d,2));

[v,ind] = min(tmp,[],3); 
index = row + size(d,1)*size(d,2)*(ind-1)+ size(d,1)*(col-1); %turn the ind to index
dm = d(index); %get the signed minimum value
```

The above code does not so efficient. Does anyone know a better choice? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating your grid of `row` and `col` values to convert `ind` into an index which you can use to index back into `d`, you can just use the *first output of `min`* which contains those minimum values along the third dimension.

```
dm = min(abs(d), [], 3);
```

Comment: Hi Suever, thanks for the reply. But, in your case, dm is the absolute value. In my case, dm is the signed value.